# How does CyberMaster regeneration work?

Tags: doctor-who, regeneration, cybermen

How does the regeneration energy in the [CyberMasters](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/CyberMaster) not destroy them? Aren't they completely made of steel?  What happens to the organic matter inside of a cyber Time Lord? Does it regrow as rotting flesh, or is it as if the Time Lord inside is not dead?

How can a CyberMaster actually regenerate at all?

Comment: How does CyberMaster regeneration work? Very well, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> How does the regeneration energy in the CyberMasters not destroy them?

Most like The Master made it so they wouldn't be damaged (as the Daleks were in [the Seige of Trenzalore](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Siege_of_Trenzalore)). He did have the Cyberium in him at the time, so he would have had intimate working knowledge of how they were built and how to make them not damage themselves in the process.

> Aren't they completely made of steel? What happens to the organic matter inside of a cyber Time Lord? Does it regrow as rotting flesh, or is it as if the Time Lord inside is not dead?

Metal + electronics + the components of whatever bodies they dissect. We don't know precisely how they all work together, but presumably when either the electronics or the organic parts are damaged beyond repair, they shut down. Apparently the regeneration energy fixes whatever is wrong with the CyberMaster so they are fully functional. That's as much as we see in that episode.

The theory at the end of the episode is

> [the Death Particle](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Death_particle) that [Ashad](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Ashad) had would completely destroy the Timelord parts of the CyberMasters.

Moving along

> How can a CyberMaster actually regenerate at all?

They have a Timelord body within them, instead of a human one.

Answer (score 2):

As with a number of things in the season finale, the information presented seems to contradict information given earlier.  in the Smith episode *Nightmare in Silver*, The Doctor's mind is invaded by Cyberman nanotech, and has partially succumbed to the assimilation process. The Doctor says that he could, if he wished, trigger a regeneration, which would burn away the cyber-tech, but he didn't want to do that.

(There is also the fact that at the time, The Doctor believed he was at the end of his regeneration cycle, and as such, believed that he could NOT regenerate, so we can assume that his threat was an empty / a clever lie.

So, if the act of regeneration would destroy any of the cyber-tech in a Time Lord's body, why would it not destroy the tech within the Cyber-Master?

We can pretty quickly assume that The Master has already thought of that, and has Done Something to prevent it. Perhaps the tech in this version is designed to survive the process, or perhaps he's made changes to the process to assume the tech is not a threat.

If one were in a "This can't happen, and here's why" mindset, one could come up with any number of things that could be seen as "proof" that the story is flawed, almost all of which could be answered at least Superficially with "The Master thought of that".

For example, since (most) Time Lords can only regenerate twelve times, his promise of endlessly repairing and regenerating warriors isn't correct. Again, since he's see the details of how regeneration was integrated into his race, he could have removed the limit for these warriors.

We can debate it till December...and probably will.

Answer (score 0):

> How does the regeneration energy in the CyberMasters not destroy them? Aren't they completely made of steel?

There isn't really much evidence that regeneration energy destroys non-biological matter. None of the Doctor's regenerations destroyed the TARDIS *except* for Ten's regeneration which was exceptionally dramatic, but even then it only caused some fires and didn't actually melt the metal or anything. Nine advised Rose to stand back while he regenerated, but previous regenerations were much more gentle - Four regenerated surrounded by his companions. It seems reasonable that the Cyber suits, being a powerful body armour, could survive this.

> What happens to the organic matter inside of a cyber Time Lord? Does it regrow as rotting flesh, or is it as if the Time Lord inside is not dead?

Cybermen are cybernetically enhanced humans. They are "upgraded", and remains of the human are inside - they aren't dead, rotting flesh. We have seen on number of occasions that they are still flesh inside, for example, Bill Potts crying inside her suit, the partially converted 'Cyberwoman' in Torchwood, the exposed brain of the Cyber leader in 'The Next Doctor' and most recently the 'Lone' Cyberman (the skeletons seen through the dark water in the episode of the same name are a bit of an anomaly - see [this question and answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/222848/how-can-they-see-the-chairs-through-the-dark-water) for more about that). So it stands to reason that the Time Lords inside the cyber suits are also "living" flesh, and regenerate at the point of death.

The real problem that I see in this plan is that the first Cybermen stories of the rebooted series showed buzz-saws working as part of the conversion process, suggesting that bits of the humans were lopped off. When the tenth Doctor lost his hand in *The Christmas Invasion* he was quickly able to grow a new one, but only because his regeneration process had not completely finished. This would suggest that, had he had a limb lopped off at some other time (ie in a cyber-conversion process) that he would not have grown a new one. A Time Lord regenerates at the point of *death* - not injury. However, if the Time Lords inside the cybersuits had bits lopped off or removed for conversion, when they regenerated, surely their bodies would be restored as a whole? Sorry, I've answered your question but asked another one.

Comment: Well, there's the bit https://youtu.be/MM0ptQJEemA?t=67 from 'Nightmare in Silver' where the Doctor explicitly states that regeneration will destroy the Cyber implants in him.

Comment: @PeteKirkham That was a bluff, he was fighting with information that the other side would not know (fake, but no way to check). Even his chess game was about this, nothing he said after he started fighting for the last part of brain can be counted as factual